# Injecting Config Values At Compile Time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm working on a project using Grunt. My project has a file named build.config.js. The configuration setting of my app are in this file. It is used as part of my build process.

Now, I have a JavaScript file in my application that is used at runtime. I need to have that configured value in my application. However, I'm not sure how to get it from a config file into my app file. Ideally, I'd like to replace the value in my app file with the configured value at compile time. However, I'm not sure how to do this.

Does anyone know if I can do this with Grunt and JavaScript? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

If your application is written in Node, you may find my answer here useful:

[Dynamic path in Yeoman build comment tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290757/dynamic-path-in-yeoman-build-comment-tag)

If not, let me know and I'll update my answer.